# Add number to the strings in the list in python

Tags: python

I want to add numbers to list of strings so I can keep count of number of items.

Assume I have a list like this:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'A', 'b', 'a', 'C', 'D', 'd']
```

I want to assign a number to each string irrespective of capital or small letters, Here's the output I'm looking for,

```
list = ['a_1', 'b_1', 'A_2', 'b_2', 'a_3', 'C_1', 'D_1', 'd_2']
```

This is what I've tried but I'm not getting the correct output

```
list = [j+f'_{i}' for i, j in enumerate(lst, 1)]
```

Comment: What is not working with your approach?

Comment: And where is your approach? Also don't use `list` since it's a python reserved name

Comment: I was only able to get this output: `[a_1, b_2, a_3, b_4, a_5, c_6, D_7, d_8]`

Comment: Add that code to the question?

Comment: So you're looking for a solution where `a = A` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I have added the code I don't know how to write the code for my condition.

Comment: @Jan Same letter should increment the number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep track of how many times you have seen a number in a dictionary, and update the count whenever you see the letter, and use the last count to append to the character.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def label(lst):

    dct = defaultdict(int)
    output = []

    #Iterate through the list
    for item in lst:

        char = item.lower()
        #Update dictionary
        dct[char] += 1

        #Create the list of characters with count appended
        output.append(f'{item}_{dct[char]}')

    return output

print(label(['a', 'b', 'A', 'b', 'a', 'C', 'D', 'd']))
```

The output will be

```
['a_1', 'b_1', 'A_2', 'b_2', 'a_3', 'C_1', 'D_1', 'd_2']
```

Also don't use `list` as a variable name, since it's a reserved python builtin name.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of the counts using a dictionary:

```py
newlist = []
counts = {}
for element in oldlist:
    if element.casefold() in counts:
        counts[element.casefold()] += 1
    else:
        counts[element.casefold()] = 1
    newlist.append(f'{element}_{counts[element.casefold()]}')
```

Comment: Tip: if you use `counts = defaultdict(int)`, you could just increment the counter and don't need to write the if-else-statement (see answer of Devesh for example)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Counter` for this to keep track of the number of times the item has been added, like:

```
from collections import Counter

def labelize(iterable):
    c = Counter()
    for item in iterable:
        sc = item.casefold()
        c[sc] += 1
        yield '{}_{}'.format(item, c[sc])
```

We can then label with:

```
>>> list(labelize(['a', 'b', 'A', 'b', 'a', 'C', 'D', 'd']))
['a_1', 'b_1', 'A_2', 'b_2', 'a_3', 'C_1', 'D_1', 'd_2']
```

We can generalize the above by using an arbitrary mapping function, like:

```
def labelize(iterable, key=lambda x: x):
    c = Counter()
    for item in iterable:
        ci = key(item)
        c[ci] += 1
        yield '{}_{}'.format(item, c[ci])
```

The equivalent here would be:

```
>>> list(labelize(['a', 'b', 'A', 'b', 'a', 'C', 'D', 'd'], str.casefold))
['a_1', 'b_1', 'A_2', 'b_2', 'a_3', 'C_1', 'D_1', 'd_2']
```

> **Note**: please do *not* use `str.lower` or `str.upper` for case matching. Certain cultures have specific rules for case matching. For example in German, the [*eszett ß* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) has as uppercase `'SS'`, by using `.tolower()`, the two would be different). The [**`str.casefold`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) is designed to map strings to a value that can be used for case-insensitive matching. See for more information [*3.13  Default Case Algorithms* of the Unicode 9 standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
original = ['a', 'b', 'A', 'b', 'a', 'C', 'D', 'd']

lowered_reversed = [i.lower() for i in original][::-1]

for i in range(len(lowered_reversed)):
    count = lowered_reversed.count(lowered_reversed[i])
    lowered_reversed[i] = lowered_reversed[i] + "_" + str(count)

new_list = lowered_reversed[::-1]

for i in range(len(original)):
    if original[i].isupper():
        new_list[i] = new_list[i].upper()

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['a_1', 'b_1', 'A_2', 'b_2', 'a_3', 'C_1', 'D_1', 'd_2']
```

Comment: will be better if second loop will be also on `range`. you even called the variable `i` which is usually for indices

Comment: Ok, I am changing.

Comment: looks better no? but why you changed to `list1`? should be `original`

Comment: By the way, yes, it looks better. ^^